# How to store cryptocurrency balance without causing floating point errors in ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, floating-point

I'm creating a rails app where users will have an account balance in ethereum and possibly other cryptocurrencies. Currently I am storing the users balance as a float. This, however, is a really bad approach as cryptocurrencies are usually divisible down to 8 digits so any floating point error will cause a huge loss/gain in funds. How can I store the users balance (what datatype should I use) as to not cause floating point errors? Thanks

Comment: "usually divisible down to 8 digits" and "the users balance" is a bit vague. The datatype depends on the values you are going to store. What range and precision has to be preserved? What is the smallest and largest value (both positive and negative) you are going to handle?

Comment: Consider the money-rails gem, it should be able to do what you want automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby has a special class for this:

BigDecimal -> https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html

Answer (score 2):

I suggest storing the values as integers. Just multiply the currency values by a million (or whatever) when you store them and convert them as needed in your application.